# excel:how to convert name-value list of repeating record structure to table/crosstab?

Tags: microsoft-excel, transform, list

**'text to columns' and pivot table are not the solutions!**

source data

```
myval: value1
mydate: 11:11:2001
myname: bob diamond
mynum: 5648
endmarker
myval: value2
mydate: 10:10:2008
myname: jimmy knapp
mynum: 6661
endmarker
```

into

```
myval            mydate           myname            mynum
value 1          11:11:2001       bob diamond       5648
value 2          10:10:2008       jimmy knapp       6661
```

the first part is fine where the delimiter also features in the date and can be achieved via:

```
 =IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)-1),"")     
 =IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1,1)),"")
```

Which nicely splits on only the first delimiter

google annoyingly for "list to table" or "list to crosstab" returns results for exactly the opposite

**EDIT**: there are about 200 fields in each record, the values always appear in the same order but some of them are not always present which means it cannot be solved directly with something like the OFFSET command which would otherwise have worked

Comment: You have field names you could use to identify the values, but is every sequence identical (all the same fields in the same order), so you could reliably use relative row number to assign values rather than decoding what goes in each column?  Are those the actual field names or just placeholders for the example?  Is the actual data just four columns?  Simple solution: for the value in each destinating column: use MID() function with starting character for that value and calculate the appropriate source row numerically.

Comment: The field names are in the same order but as I have now realised after trying to solve this with OFFSET, some of the records do not contain all fields and there are about 200 fields. I will edit the Q to reflect this

Comment: So the output you want will have about 200 columns?

Comment: Yes which means the list to table thing in MSWord won't work either

Comment: One approach-- create 3 helper columns: parse the field name and value and add a record number based on the endmarkers (to match the destinating record/row number).  For the value in each column, do a lookup of the column heading in the helper column array within the matching record number.  Another approach: use Access.

Comment: Is a **VBA** macro acceptable ??

Comment: It's looking increasingly like that, replete with 200 branch Case statement :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that your source data is in column **A** of *Sheet1*:

[image]

First place the column headers in *Sheet2*

Then run this short macro:

```
Sub DataReOrganizer()
   Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long, v As String
   Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
   N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   K = 2

   For i = 1 To N
      v = s1.Cells(i, "A").Text
      If v = "endmarker" Then
         K = K + 1
      Else
         ary = Split(v, ": ")
         MsgBox ary(1)
         If ary(0) = "myval" Then s2.Cells(K, 1) = ary(1)
         If ary(0) = "mydate" Then s2.Cells(K, 2) = Chr(39) & ary(1)
         If ary(0) = "myname" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = ary(1)
         If ary(0) = "mynum" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = ary(1)
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

to produce this in *Sheet2*:

[image]

The *Chr(39)* is used to preserve your date format and prevent Excel from changing it into a time.

Comment: It works! But some extra gotchas were to be found in the form of odd hidden characters. Once removed and the script amended (using excel) to create the other 196 odd columns it ran fine. Thanks

Comment: This does answer the question but I now realise that one of the fields is multiline and only has the identifier on the first row which I will have to try and catch. I will post back if and when I figure out the solution (not handling this is resulting in lines 2 to *n* of said field being dumped)